# HTML5 <canvas> without anti-aliasing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, antialiasing

I use `fillRect(x, y, 9, 9)` with integer values and see smoothed rectangles (see below). I tried the following with no luck:

```
this.ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
this.ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

var iStrokeWidth = 1;  
var iTranslate = (iStrokeWidth % 2) / 2;
this.ctx.translate(iTranslate, iTranslate);
```

i would like to see a line of 1 pixel between blue blocks, but i see smoothed gap:

[image: aliased fills]

Answer (score 3):

Just add 0.5 pixel to the positions (or pre-translate half pixel):

```
fillRect(x + 0.5, y + 0.5, 9, 9);
```

This works because for some reason the canvas coordinate system define start of a pixel from the pixel's center. When drawn canvas actually has to sub-pixel the single point producing 4 anti-aliased pixels. By adding 0.5 you move it from center to the pixel's corner so it matches with the screen's coordinate system and no sub-pixeling has to take place.

These only affects images, not shapes btw.:

```
this.ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
this.ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
```